# what is the difference between wsgi, python_wsgi, wsgi server and mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am very confused in below terms,
1. wsgi
2. python_wsgi
3. wsgi server 
4. mod_wsgi
5. python web server gateway interface(PEP3333)

what are these for? I know wsgi is just an interface or a specification between app and server but why these so many terms are used in docs. How I am gonna use this with apache? What is wsgi server for? This is pretty confusing. Some simple and detailed explaination would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Also see e.g. https://www.fullstackpython.com/deployment.html

Answer (score 2):

**WSGI** stands for **Web Server Gateway Interface**

It describes the way a server such as Apache communicates with a python program (web application).

A **WSGI server** is a server that complies with the WSGI standard.

**Mod_WSGI** is an Apache module that supports the WSGI standard and thus allows Apache to be a WSGI server. It allows you to host python programs through Apache.

**[PEP3333](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/)** is where the technical aspects of WSGI standard are defined.

Comment: So, you mean if I need to use apache server then I will write my wsgi app according to PEP3333 and then put that .py file in some apache folder? or I will create some server side as well along with that .py file, as defined in PEP3333 and put that file in some apache folder?

Comment: apache and wsgi servers are alternatives?

Comment: mod wsgi lets u make apache into a wsgi server.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: To quote from the project page: The mod_wsgi package...[allows]...hosting Python based web applications on top of the Apache web server.

Comment: Here's is a list of WSGI servers: http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/servers.html

Comment: Can anyone suggest me any good tutorial links on paste+wsgi?? I am lacking the basics, i guess.

Comment: That is a different question which you should probably create a new question for.

Comment: Its not a question, it is a request